# Subtracting a specific row's value from other values in a dplyr group_by() tbl

Tags: r, dplyr

Writing the title for this was more difficult than expected.

I have data that look like this:

```
   scenario type value
1         A    U   922
2         A    V   291
3         A    W   731
4         A    X   970
5         A    Y   794
6         B    U   827
7         B    V    10
8         B    W   517
9         B    X    97
10        B    Y   681
11        C    U    26
12        C    V   410
13        C    W   706
14        C    X   865
15        C    Y   385
16        D    U   473
17        D    V   561
18        D    W   374
19        D    X   645
20        D    Y   217
21        E    U   345
22        E    V    58
23        E    W   437
24        E    X   106
25        E    Y   292
```

What I'm trying to do is subtract the value from `type == W` from all the values in each scenario.  So, for example, after this command is done, scenario **A** would look like this:

```
  scenario type value
1        A    U   191
2        A    V  -440
3        A    W     0
4        A    X   239
5        A    Y    63
```

...and so forth

I figure I can use `dplyr::group_by()` and `mutate()` but I'm not sure what to put in the mutate command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr`.  In the `mutate` function you can just query `which` has type of "W" then subtract that from the original value.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(scenario) %>% mutate(value = value - value[which(type == "W")])
# A tibble: 25 x 3
# Groups: scenario [5]
#   scenario type  value
#   <fct>    <fct> <int>
# 1 A        U       191
# 2 A        V      -440
# 3 A        W         0
# 4 A        X       239
# 5 A        Y        63
# 6 B        U       310
# 7 B        V      -507
# 8 B        W         0
# 9 B        X      -420
#10 B        Y       164
## ... with 15 more rows
```